# What is the difference between Visual Studio & Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, difference

What is the difference between `Visual Studio` and `Visual Studio Code`.

What should I choose to develop apps and webapps with `Python`, `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio is more for making apps and using programming languages like c/c++, java, and c#. It is also better for coding in unity or unreal engine but vs code works fine too. Visual studio code, is more for making **web** applications like with html, css, javascript. Visual studio code is also good for some server side languages like asp.net, asp, php, node.js and also works great for SQL.